# NG2-Charts Error Can't Bind Datasets To Base-Charts In Angular2 After Update

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular-cli

After updating OSX to Sierra and angular-cli my Angular 2 app broke. I now am receiving errors regarding `ng2-charts`

I have tried to revert back and even tried rolling back further to other versions of Node, NPM and Angular-cli but nothing will clear the errors and allow the app to render.

These are the errors I am getting which reference every line I am trying to bind datasets to base-chart.

Binding

```
 <base-chart class="chart" 
[datasets]="lineChart1Data" [labels]="lineChart1Labels" [options]="lineChart1Options" [colors]="lineChart1Colours" [legend]="lineChart1Legend" [chartType]="lineChart1Type" (chartHover)="chartHovered($event)" (chartClick)="chartClicked($event)"
     style="height:70px;"></base-chart>
```

Error

```
zone.js:344Unhandled Promise rejection: Template parse errors:
Can't bind to 'datasets' since it isn't a known property of 'base-chart'.
1. If 'base-chart' is an Angular component and it has 'datasets' input, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. If 'base-chart' is a Web Component then add "CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA" to the '@NgModule.schema' of this component to suppress this message.
 ("iv>
                <div class="chart-wrapper p-x-1">
                    <base-chart class="chart" [ERROR ->][datasets]="lineChart1Data" [labels]="lineChart1Labels" [options]="lineChart1Options" [colors]="lineC"): DashboardComponent@19:46
```

I have been working on this app for weeks without any problems and now this has been crushing me all day, Any ideas?

Comment: I got the same error. Did you find a solution ?

Comment: @Sam yes I did find the answer. You can see it in this git post I made. Also I added the answer to this post so other people can find it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There was breaking changes in 1.4.0 and you need to use `<canvas baseChart...></canvas>` instead of `<base-chart...></base-chart>`.

As mentioned in [this git issue](https://github.com/valor-software/ng2-charts/issues/455#issuecomment-252442739)

See the [breaking changes here](https://github.com/valor-software/ng2-charts/blob/development/CHANGELOG.md#breaking-changes)

> BREAKING CHANGES
>
> charts: - base-chart component became baseChart directive so you need
>   to convert

`<base-chart...></base-chart>`

> to

`<canvas baseChart...></canvas>`

> and most probably wrap in

```
 <div style='display:block'>...</div>
```

Comment: yes, I saw that shortly after I've asked here and I forgot to get back to you. Thanks !